# Jumping to a node within a Watson Dialog

Tags: ibm-watson

In reviewing the API documentation, I didn't see a way to jump into a specific area of a Watson Dialog template. This might be useful if you determine a user's intent (e.g. using Watson Natural Language Classifier) and want to go directly to the relevant section of a comprehensive Watson Dialog template. Is there a way to do this or is it better to have a separate dialog for each possible entry point or is there some other way to think about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would simply pass that input node in as the user input for them as if they were at that point in a conversation.

For nlc specifically, the way I see it is that you would likely want your classes to match your input nodes so that when passing you do not need to do any manipulation in between.

User: open an account
Class = open account
Input: open account

Note that you will need to initialize a conversation first so you have a conversation and client id, from there it's a simple as passing it in as the users input with the API call.