# Is there a way to jump to a dialog Node in Watson by code?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

In Watson-conversation one of the first things I do is asking the user an Id. I receive that in python and check in a simple db I have if the id exists there (it is quite a simple logic).

Now, what I want is to jump to Node 1 if the user does not exist in my db. So I was looking for something **in python** to do so, as Watson cannot check my db.

I have been looking at several info. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41714675/in-watson-conversation-how-to-jump-to-another-node-from-one-node-in-procedure) was the most usefull, but I searched for [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286304/jumping-to-a-node-within-a-watson-dialog).

It also looked interesting to me to look for slots and handlers, but again, that cannot check in my simple database.

I was expecting something like this:

- Node 1: asking id
- If id exists then:
- Node 2: Hi $name! blah blah blah
- but if id does not exist Jump to Node 1.

I have made a simple function so as to understand what I want to do:

```
def checkingId(bot, update):
    message=update.message.text #let's suppose it is already parsed, to make it simpler
    result=cursor.execute("select name from users where id=message")

    if(result!=None): #so if the id exists in the table
        #no problem here, keep it going like normal watson would do
                whatever()

    else:
        jumpToNode1InWatson (???)
```

I have also seen that there might be this parameter `dialog_node": "node1 or whatever it is"` in the json(?), so I may access this via python, but I have not found anything relevant about it.

[source of that](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/issues/123)

Thanks in advance. If you think the question can be edited to improve it, comment it and I'll try my best to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [IBM Cloud solution tutorial for a database-driven chatbot](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html) has code to interact with a DB from Watson Assistant. The related GitHub repo shows it for Db2 and PostgreSQL. It is done via an IBM Cloud Functions action. The other option is to use a [client-side dialog action](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions).

Now, once you checked for the ID you would set a variable. In a dialog tree you could then have the condition that the ID is present or has a certain value to process a dialog node or switch into that branch of the dialog tree. Thus, you would force Watson Assistant into your intended processing.

Comment: Essentially you can use the Assistant Dialog to switch to the appropriate node, by having your application set context variables and/or the input text, to force a node match or trigger an appropriate digression.

Comment: Thanks a lot Henrik! I have also though about something: in the end, as I am implementing a telegram-watson communication, I thought that not all that the user sends from telegram, needs to be passed to watson. I can do some cleaning and checks, and set a variable! And also the other way around, not everything watson responds must be sent to the user via TL, as I can clean and do some checks before doing so! But I'll be taking a look at that, as it looks much cleaner!

Comment: @chughts The problem is how to force the node when you cannot pass to watson the id after it is checked! But I think I figured it out. If you already have the conversational design, you can "force" by cleaning and checking the data, doing stuff inside, and then responding!

Comment: Check out Botkit and botkit middleware for Watson Assistant: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware for inspiration or for direct use